# Is the "Push-Down" Quantization of Chern-Simons Theory part of a more general approach to Quantization?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, phase-space, quantization, chern-simons-theory

I've recently started reading Axelrod, Della Pietra and Witten's [original paper](https://doi.org/10.4310/jdg/1214446565) about the quantization of Chern-Simons theory. I'd like to know if the "push-down" quantization strategy they use for Chern-Simons Theory has developed into a more general approach to quantization? If so, a short summary would be appreciated.

In particular, many things in their "push-down" strategy seem to work out nicely in the Chern-Simons case. However I could imagine, with a little more effort, perhaps they could be generalized. As their paper is thirty years old now, I was wondering if this has happened?

I have heard people discuss "push-forward" quantization using $\text{Spin}^{\mathbb{C}}$ structures. Is this a generalization to Axelrod, Pietra and Witten's approach? Or is the name misleading me?